# Adding hours in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time

I figured this would be a very simple problem but I haven't found a solution anywhere.

I am creating a scheduling program in PHP and mySQL. The shifts have a startTime and endTime, each of which are stored as TIME in mySQL.

I want to add up the total hours for an employee during the week, so I tried:

```
$shifts = [...] //shifts for the week
$totalTime = 0; //I've also tried "0:0:0" and strtotime("0:00:00");

for($d = 0; $d < 7; $d++){
    $start = strtotime($shift_types[$shifts[$d]]['ShiftType']['start_time']);
    $end = strtotime($shift_types[$shifts[$d]]['ShiftType']['end_time']);
    echo date("g:ia", $start) . ' / ' . date("g:i a", $end); 
    $totalTime += ($end-$start);
    }
}
```

The problem with this, is that $totalTime doesn't come out to any reasonable number. I think this is because PHP is treating $totalTime as a timestamp since 1970, which would result in something completely different. All I really want is a value of net hours, it doesn't need to have any date-ish values associated with it.

I should mention that I'm displaying the total time with

```
echo date("g:i", $totalTime);
```

When it is run with a start of 9:30:00 and an end of 16:15:00, it displays "1:45".
When the total time isn't touched (because there are no shifts), it displays "7:00".

Comment: what is it coming up with and what values are you testing with as start/end? The result of the code should be in seconds so you might need to divide by 3600 (number of seconds in an hour) to get hours.

Comment: You might want to look into [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I added the details to the post. It doesn't seem like a division issue though.

Comment: As @Mike noted, you can do all this with MySQL. No need to fetch results and let PHP calc it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime` returns a Unix timestamp, the number of seconds since the epoch represented by that time.  So working with seconds (and starting `$totalTime` at zero) is the correct approach.  If you want the number of hours, you need to: `$totalTime = $totalTime / (60 * 60);` after your loop (divide by 3600 seconds / hour).

Comment: It makes sense theoretically, but then why is it displaying hours even if $totalTime is still equal to 0?

Comment: Are you sure that `$totalTime` is what you think it is?  Print that out right before you make the call to `date` after the loop.

Comment: You're right, I don't know what I was thinking trying to format $totalTime using date. Changing it to echo $totalTime/(60*60) worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want to do:

```
$t1 = strtotime("2013-01-01 00:00:00");
$t2 = strtotime("2013-01-15 00:00:00");

echo round(($t2-$t1)/3600) ." hours". PHP_EOL;
```

Or you could look to use two `DateTime` objects and the `diff()` method as described in my blog post http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/working-with-date-and-time-in-php/